# Injected bean becomes null after using AOP

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-aop

I am using `Spring4` along with `Spring Boot`.

Before I tired to use AOP, my Bean(CommandService),which is used in the controller, is auto injected well, but after I tired to use AOP to collect some debug message, the bean becomes null!

Here is my `Application.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"hello","wodinow.weixin.jaskey"})
public class Application extends  {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    LogUtil.info("Beans provided by Spring Boot:");
    String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    Arrays.sort(beanNames);
    for (String beanName : beanNames) {
        LogUtil.info(beanName);
    }
    LogUtil.info("Application Boots completes!");
}

@Bean
public CommandService commandService(){
    LogUtil.debug("CommandService.getInstance()"+ CommandService.getInstance()) ;//here indeed I could see spring executes this and returns a object when application boots
    return CommandService.getInstance();//This returns a singleton instance
}
```

}

My controller that throws null pointer:

```
@Controller
public class CoreController {

    @Autowired
    CommandService commandService;//here the service is null after using aop

    //...some request methods
}
```

The Aspect which I added just now:

```
//if I comment out these two annoations, the bean will be auto injected well
@Aspect
@Component
public class LogAspect {
@Pointcut("execution(* wodinow.weixin.jaskey..*.*(..))")
    private void debug_log(){};

    @Around("debug_log()")
    public void debug(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
        LogUtil.debug("enter "+joinPoint.getSignature());
        try{
           joinPoint.proceed();
           LogUtil.debug("returns from "+joinPoint.getSignature());
        }
        catch(Throwable t){
            LogUtil.error(t.getMessage()+"occurs in "+joinPoint.getSignature(),t);
            throw t;
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to Spring, can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Your advice doesn't return anything.

Comment: @zeroflagL , what do you mean doesn't return anything? Do I need to post anything else to describe the problem?

Comment: `commandService()` returns a `CommandService` bean. When you use AOP then it's no longer called directly, but `debug()` is called instead. And `debug()` doesn't return anything. So how are you supposed to get a `CommandService` instance?

Comment: Oh! I guess what you mean, you mean my AOP method debug have intercept the method of `commandService()`, and that method should return `CommandService` , but it does not? So the problem occurs? I am new to Spring AOP. this is my first time to write this, would you please help me with a solution with an answer?

Comment: Take a look at [Spring docs for @Around](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice). The advice has certain requirements for its input/output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@ComponentScan` is trying to resolve and autowire your dependencies into `CoreController`. When it tries to resolve the dependency it finds the `@Bean` in your `Application` class. It then tries to resolve this dependency by calling `Application.commandService()`. When this method is called, it sees the matching `@Pointcut` and invokes your advice method. Since your `@Advice` is not returning anything, the callers will also see that nothing was returned, and it will say that that resolution of that dependency returned `null`.

The fix here is just  to change your `@Around` advice to return the value of your invocation.

```
@Around("debug_log()")
public Object debug(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
    LogUtil.debug("enter "+joinPoint.getSignature());
    try{
        // return the invocation
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
    catch(Throwable t){
        LogUtil.debug(t.getMessage()+"occurs in "+joinPoint.getSignature(),t);
        throw t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean actully we should let every around advice to return a Object?

Comment: It should generally return something or throw an exception. I can't think of any case where the @Around advice would not return follow that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You are used

```
joinPoint.proceed();
```

without return just add return to be

```
return joinPoint.proceed();
```